# unsigned int comparision in c

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, unsigned

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int c = -1;
    char *s = "Abc";
    char *x = "defhe";
    ((strlen(s)-strlen(x))>c)? printf(s): printf(x);
}
```

the value of `c` is `4294967295` and the value of `(strlen(s)-strlen(x))` is `4294967294` it should print the `x` but it is printing the s value.I am not getting why it is like that

Comment: isn't that strange to put `-1` in an unsigned int in the first place?

Comment: maybe c is not evaluated until that line and directly exchanged by constant literal -1 so no promoting occurs?

Comment: Those `printf` are really strange.

Comment: why are they strange? without formatting `printf` acts like `puts`.

Comment: I wrote that code in c

Comment: Fix your printf call: printf("%s", ((strlen(s)-strlen(x))>c)? s: x);

Comment: You should definitely be getting a warning assigning a negative number to an unsigned int.  Why not make it an int if it's signed?

Comment: When I compiled this with `gcc -Wall` I got *format string is not a string literal* for each `printf`.

Comment: I just wanting to know how unsigned int comparisions works. Thats i intentionally assigned -1 to unsigned int c. if its 0 or more than 1 then i understood the flow diff of strlens are very larger than c so it will print the s.

Comment: Found an interesting link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169692/assigning-negative-numbers-to-an-unsigned-int

Comment: if c is 0 then it is printing s only its taking left operand as unsigned int

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `unsigned int c = -1;` is an idiomatic way of setting `c` to the maximum value.  `unsigned int c = -1u;` or perhaps `unsigned int c = UINT_MAX;` would be a bit more clear.

Comment: @cdarke Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707661/4392605)

Comment: Why not just do `printf("%s", (strlen(s) > strlen(x)) ? s : x);`

Comment: I know that i want to know how unsigned int comparisions and stuff thats why i wrote the program like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the value of c is 4294967295 and the value of (strlen(s)-strlen(x)) is 4294967294

It isn't necessarily true that `(strlen(s)-strlen(x))` yields `4294967294`. It depends on the value of `SIZE_MAX` on your system.

If `SIZE_MAX` is `18446744073709551615` (typically on a 64-bit system) then `(strlen(s)-strlen(x))` will be `18446744073709551614` which is obviously greater than `4294967295` (assuming `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295`). Hence, you see `printf(s);` getting printed.

Use a `printf()` statement to see the values and understand:

```
printf("%zu %u\n", strlen(s)-strlen(x), c);
```

Comment: From the ANSI standard (I don't have C99, but it's the same behavior):A.6.2 Undefined behavior
 * An arithmetic operation is invalid (such as division or modulus by 0)
   or produces a result that cannot be represented in the space
   provided (such as overflow or underflow) ($3.3).  strlen() returns size_t which is unsigned.  You're underflowing and in the realms of undefined behavior.  I've seen this be inconsistent in statements compiled by the same compiler, let alone one compiler to the next.

Comment: @BigBobby  "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,..." C11dr §6.2.5 9 This is no UB with the comparison.

Comment: @BigBobby There's no undefined behaviour in the code. All the conversions (and promotions) happen as defined by the C standard. Please explain which "operation is invalid". By the way, unsigned types do *not* overflow (or underflow). They just wrap around using reduction modulo.

Comment: @chux - I said underflow, not overflow.

Comment: @BigBobby There's no "underflow" either.

Comment: @usr - Two unsigneds are being subtracted and being compared to an unsigned.  What promotion do you think is happening?

Comment: @BigBobby True that our comment said "underflow", yet that makes no difference.  Still no UB.

Comment: @BigBobby Unsigned integers, by definition, can't overflow or underflow. Their "wrap around" behaviour is well-defined by the C standard and it's not undefined behaviour. Please do not downvote if you don't know that.

Comment: @usr - Are you trying to strictly define underflow as when a number gets too small to be represented by a float, as opposed to getting a negative result when two unsigned integers are subtracted?  The standard refers to both as underflow...the OP is subtracting two unsigned numbers and underflowing, and assigning a negative number to a unsigned integer in the first place.

Comment: @BigBobby The conversion of `-1` to `unsigned` is well defined per "if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type"  Unclear if you see this as an issue.

Comment: @BigBobby-- where in the Standard is underflow resulting from subtraction of `unsigned` types mentioned?

Comment: @usr To be fair, the spec is not obvious about  unsigned "underflow" - yet it is discernible in the complete `§6.2.5 9` , which at first glance looks like underflow is not defined (hence UB), when it really is defined with an understanding of "reduced modulo".  UV for a good answer.

Comment: Just read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is (*cough* particularly the answer posted by yours faithfully *cough*)

Comment: @chux I agree that reading/decoding the C standard isn't always an easy task. But if I were in that position, I'd read/verify the standard more keenly after the first comment (given that more than one person disagrees with it). Certainly wouldn't downvote before ascertaining my facts. Given that BigBobby hasn't responded, I'd presume he realized his mistake and all is well now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you outputted the expression `strlen(s)-strlen(x)` using format specifier `%u` for example like this

```
printf( "%u\n", ( unsigned int )( strlen(s)-strlen(x)));
printf( "%u\n", c );
```

In this case the output is indeed is equal to

```
4294967294
4294967295
```

However if you output these expressions using casting to the type `size_t` and the format specifier `%zu` you will get

```
printf( "%zu\n", strlen(s)-strlen(x));
printf( "%zu\n", ( size_t ) c );
```

and

```
18446744073709551614
4294967295
```

So the value of expression `strlen(s)-strlen(x)` is greater than the value of the variable `c` casted to the type `size_t`.

You could get the expected by you result if `sizeof( size_t )` would be equal to `sizeof( unsigned int )`.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of implicit conversion from `int` / `unsigned int` to `size_t` type is error prone and difficult to detect. Static code analyzers like PVS-Studio are very good in finding such bugs automatically.

Comment: What implicit conversion? The only implicit conversion taking place here is `c` getting promoted to `size_t` in the expression `(strlen(s)-strlen(x))>c`, which is irrelevant to the result and the question.

Comment: @Lundin Is not `unsigned int c = -1;` also an implied conversion of an `int` to `unsigned`?  (which is also secondary to the crux of the post)

Comment: @chux Well yeah, but even if it was written as `-1u` it wouldn't affect the outcome. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I mean conversion in expression `(strlen(s)-strlen(x))>c`. It's better to make such conversions explicit to avoid unexpected results like in this question.