# Why printf(char[]) generates a warning, meanwhile printf("asdf") doesn't

Tags: c, gcc, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

I have very simple question: Why when I make `char[] s = "hi"; printf(s)` it issues a warning: "warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments", meanwhile `printf("aa")` doesn't.

I've already read a difference between char array and string literal (one is `const char const*` and another is `char*`), but from `printf()` signature:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions

I see that it's suitable for any of that types. So my question is why `printf("aaa")` don't issue any warnings (does it somehow checks that literal is a const, meanwhile array isn't)?

Comment: FWIW, VC++ does not complain about non-constant literals.

Comment: Which compiler does this to your code?

Comment: @Mystical, I agree. VC doesn't complain. Wonder why the other compiler complians or why VC doesn't?

Comment: @Jay gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GNU compiler and a lot of other compilers these days do indeed check the format strings for the `printf`-family against the arguments supplied.  The compiler is warning that it cannot do this for non-literal strings.

Using a non-literal format string is considered to be a bad practice.  Using a format string that you do not control is much worse.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that because string literal was copied into an array, compiler doesn't know what that array contains at compile time, thus it can't check if it content is a good format string along with supplied arguments.

Comment: But why then `const char* s = "hi"; printf(s)` produces warning too?

Comment: Oh, I found it `const char const* s = "hi"; printf(s)` doesn't produce any errors. So `const char const*` seems to be the type of a string literal.

Comment: Because someone can assign a different pointer to `s`.

Comment: @Jens, ty. yes, I realized it a bit later.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that there were a bunch of security issues around 10-15 years ago caused by people assuming that it was safe to call printf(s) where "s" had user supplied input. Many compilers added warnings for this to avoid the issues. If you want to just print out a string, use puts() instead. If you're not absolutely certain that the string you're sending into printf doesn't contain '%' characters, you should use printf("%s", s);

Answer (score 1):

I bet in the second case the compiler sees that the string has no format in it, and as such is not dangerous:

```
/* "aa" is not dangerous, so do not display a warning */
printf("aa")
```

In the first case, the compiler may not be able to see the value of the format string, so it can not validate it:

```
/* the compiler doesn't know the content of the memory region pointed by `s`, so
   he can't determine if it's dangerous or not. Then display a warning */
printf(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know if this is *the* reason for the warning, but it is *a* reason.

Since the number of arguments to `prinrf` is depending on the number of conversion specifiers, it is highly uncommon *not* to use a string literal as format string (i.e., likely an error). Moreover, if the format string is not a literal, it does come from somewhere else - user or file input, for example. In this case, a faulty (or malicious) input could crash your program, or worse, inject code (i.e., security flaw).

In any case, if you want to print something that is not a literal, and have no format arguments, you are most likely looking for `puts`, not `printf` anyway. (IMHO, `puts` is the single most underused function in the C library. Have you *ever* seen a "hello, world" using it?)

Comment: I've read a bit about `puts`.