# Custom Print Function with Timestamp giving warning

Tags: c++, c, timestamp, printf

I made a custom print function which prints the message with a timestamp. But when I compile it the compiler says that "format string is not a string literal". It still compiles fine, but I'm a bit bugged by this error and since the compiler also says that this might be insecure, so I want to fix it.

```
void Log(const char *message, ...)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm* timeinfo;
    char timestamp[11];

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(timestamp, 11, "%X: ", timeinfo);

    fprintf(stdout, timestamp); // format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);
    vfprintf(stdout, message, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}
```

I tried changing the `timestamp` to a `const char*` but then `strftime` wouldn't accept it and the warning was still there.

How do I fix this, and is there any way to optimize this function (since I don't know a lot about the `C IO library`)?

Comment: It's a proper warning.  You need fprintf(stdout, "%s", timestamp);

Comment: Here's the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments

Answer (score 2):

```
fprintf(stdout, timestamp);
```

`fprintf` is for formatted output directed by a format string. Calling without no arguments but the format string is a bit of misuse, and is slow to boot. To be safe using `fprintf`, you should use `fprintf (stdout, "%s", timestamp);`

Alternatively, just use `fputs (timestamp, stdout);` This bypasses the parsing of the format string and just prints the string to standard output, as is. This is exactly what you want, and it's faster because `fputs` doesn't parse the string to be printed.

Comment: Or he can just use `puts(timestamp);` and remove the second call to `fprintf()` as `puts` appends a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s", timestamp);
```

The problem is that if your timestamp string were to contain %s or similiar, then the fprintf function would look for an additional argument (which you didn't provide).