# How to fix the following warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MACRO_TEST(MESSAGE,args...) { \
  const char *A[] = {MESSAGE}; \
  printf("this is a test\n");\
  if(sizeof(A) > 0) \
    printf(*A,##args); \
}
int main () {
    MACRO_TEST();
    MACRO_TEST("hello %d\n",5);
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it, It provides a warning message:

```
test.c:78:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

What is the cause of the warning and How to fix it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining about this line

```
printf(*A,##args);
```

Change it to

```
printf(""MESSAGE, ##args);
```

Comment: If I changed to this line `printf(MESSAGE, ##args);`, It will provide compilation error. In this step `MACRO_TEST();`

Answer (score 0):

You do realise that your first argument to printf is an array of pointers to char, right?

I would be inclined to add "this is a test" to the original printf, and append (using ##) MESSAGE, and then args (possibly without ##, but not sure).

Comment: He uses *A, not A , so the argument is not an array.

Comment: Ah, good point. The remainder of my comment still applies tho.