# Concatenating an int to a string or converting in C

Tags: c, string, int, concatenation, string-concatenation

Im looking for a 6 digit random number on the end of foo-, I have been trying for a few hours now with no success. only error messages

```
note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

Ive tried to convert the int to char but it just doesn't like it, My code is below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int r = rand();

  printf(concat("foo-", r));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: passing an `int` to a function as `char*` argument doesn't automatically convert it to a string representation so you have to print it explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand();
char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
snprintf(str, 7, "%d", r);

if (strlen(str) < 6) {  /* if r had less than 6 digits */
    sprintf(str, "%06d", r);
}

char* s = concat("foo-", str);
printf("%s",s);
free(str);
free(s);

return 0;
```

from http://joequery.me/code/snprintf-c/ :

> `int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);` 
>   `str` is the buffer where printf output will be redirected to. `size` is the maximum number of bytes(characters) that will be written to the
>   buffer, including the terminating null character that snprintf
>   automatically places for you. The `format` and the optional `...`
>   arguments are just the string formats like "%d", myint as seen in
>   printf.

so, in order to get a 6 digit number converted, you specify in `snprintf()` the `size` argument to `7` (you include a null character).

`sprintf()` function sends formatted output to a string pointed to by the first argument (in our case this is `str`). `%06d` format provides that to `str` at least 6 digits will be sent.

### CONCLUSION

you want to convert a 6 digit number to a char array. if the number had at least 6 digits, with `snprintf()` you will get the first 6 digits of the number that was converted. if it has less than 6 digits, the `sprintf()` will add zeroes at the beginning until there are 6 digits. so, if `r = 101;` the result would be `000101`.

---

note that with your usage of `concat` function:

```
printf(concat("foo-",r));
```

compiler warns about (gcc in my case):

> warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
>   [-Wformat-security]

`printf()` function needs to know the format of the string argument that is passed. there's a nice answer about it right here : [warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

Comment: Or just do sprintf(str, "foo-%d", r) and you can skip the concat!

Comment: `%06d` format will print the value with at least 6 characters, not as you expected. You should use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) instead of sprintf to make sure that the printed value doesn't overflow the buffer

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc i edited my answer. c.fogelklou i think that OP wants to use concat, but what you say is right.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
printf("foo-%d", r);
```

or

```
char buffer[10];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", r);
char *c = concat("foo-", r);
printf("%s", c);
free(c);
```

This will use your function. Please read the manual pages for `sprintf` and `printf`

Comment: Also this avoids your memory leak

Comment: I tried to edit - I think you meant "%d" instead of "5d" in the second line of your second suggestion, right?  I couldn't edit because edits need to be at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

In the example I'm using `sprintf` to convert `int` to `char[]`. Also I'm using modulo operation to ensure the result will have no more than 6 digits. The `%06d` argument for `sprintf` will ensure that the result will have no less than 6 digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char buf[7] = { 0 };
    int r;

    srand(time(NULL));

    r = rand() % 1000000;
    sprintf(buf, "%06d", r);

    printf("foo-%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs when you attempt to call `concat` with the `int` value `r` as the second argument. Notice your definition of concat:

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2);
```

The second argument is `char *s2`. In your program you attempt to call it with:

```
int r = rand();

printf(concat("foo-", r));
```

`r` is an integer. Try this to correct the problem:

```
int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand();
    char str[] = "bar";

    printf(concat("foo-", str));

    return 0;
}
```