# Conversion of chars and ints in C

Tags: c, char, integer

C Programming. I'm learning C (again), and I'm making some basic programs. This one involves a function that gets an int. The function adds it to a string using `strcat`. The problem is `strcat` doesn't take ints. So, my question, an easy one, is this how to convert an int to char. (I have Googled it and looked on your site. `itoa` will not work sorry...)
Here's my code

```
char total[1000];
strcat(total, "I am");
char buff[1024];
sprintf(buff, "%s %d", total, age);
strcat(total, msg);
printf("%s", total);
```

Comment: Please do not use `strcat()`, it is unsafe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating an int to a string or converting in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464745/concatenating-an-int-to-a-string-or-converting-in-c)

Comment: What would be a replacement? That is understandable?

Comment: @yuxuantim `snprintf()`.

Comment: @yuxuantim You google for "snprintf manual" and you find [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html). Then you read it and act accordingly.

Comment: `strcat` is not in any way unsafe. It can be unsafely used. It is unsafely used when it is asked to copy N bytes into a location that has < N bytes of room. (Note that N bytes includes the terminating null byte.)

Comment: `snprintf` is complicated to use and unnecessary if all you want to do is convert a single `int` value to text. The number of digits needed can be inferred from the range of that value. If you have some large-ish buffer like 512 bytes, no possible value of `int` on any compiler can overflow it with digits.

Comment: @user3477950: `strcat` can be used perfectly safely as long as you ensure that there's enough space in the target array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) (int to ascii) function. And then combine the result with `strcat` to get your full string.

But [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) (or `snprintf`) is a better choice. You don't need `strcat` at all.

Like this:

```
char buff[1024];
sprintf(buff, "%s %d", your_string, your_int);
```

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function; some common compilers don't support it.

Comment: @user3553031 that's why I added the `sprintf` option. :-)

Comment: What does variable buff do?

Comment: Can I make the buff smaller?

Comment: buff variable plays a role of container. ``sprintf`` will save data there of format provided in second argument. you can make it bigger or smaller. read about ``sprintf`` and ``snprintf`` function also. the latter is safer to use.

Comment: `snprintf` isn't a better choice than `sprintf` if all you're converting is a single `int`, and the buffer has so much storage that no `int` representation known to man can overflow it with digits.

Comment: @Kaz But it is otherwise, and it's better to have a habit of using *generally* safer functions, even if they don't gain anything in some cases.

Comment: @user3477950 I do not agree. The only habit you need is that of thinking critically about what you're doing. `snprintf` is awkward to use. Not all versions of it are C99 compliant, and so you have to deal with different return value semantics. On top of that, here is the stupid kicker, the `wchar_t` version `swprintf` has different return value behavior, which will bite you if you're internationalizing text-manipulating code.

Comment: @Kaz Im moving a 2 digit int max from myself not from input so it would be safe