# if exit(0) of shared library exits program too?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, exit

I have one program that uses shared library. In shared library, error case they have written exit(0). So if that function is called then exit(0) will be executed of shared library.

Will it exit my program too ?

Comment: Yes it will exit the whole program.

Comment: Yes, the shared libraries are executed in context of your process, therefore exiting from a shared library will affect whole process

Comment: Where is the library function called from?

Comment: See [Should we use `exit()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501142/should-we-use-exit-in-c) — and there's an analogous [How to end C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250934/how-to-end-c-code).  Both have cross-references to related questions.

Comment: You can't exit part of code. You can only exit whole process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it  terminates the calling process immediately.SIGCHLD signal will be  send to process which  inherited by process 1 or init.