# C program warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, char, printf

I am using -

```
char str[200];
...
sprintf(str,"%s", val) 
msg(str);
sprintf(str, "%s: %s",timestr,"\n recv -");
msg(str);
... 
} 
void msg(const char str[]) 
{ 
 ...
fprintf(fp, str);
 ...
}
```

warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `fprintf()` if you want to print a constant string.

Use [`fputs(str, fp)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputs).

If you feel you must use `fprintf()`, add the formatting string i.e. use `fprintf(fp, "%s", str);`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your

```
fprintf(fp, str);
```

to

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
             ^
             |
```

In your code, you're missing the format specifier `"%s"`.

Please check the man page  of `fprintf()` [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) for more details.

Comment: @KK oh is it? if you kindly let me know the reason, it'll be so good of you.