# Getting a “format not a string literal and no format arguments” warning while using GTK+2

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, gcc-warning, gtk2

I am getting an error like this:

```
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
                                              GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
(const gchar*)message);
                   ^
```

because of this function:

```
static void show_message (gchar *message, GtkMessageType type) {
  GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, 0, type,
                                             GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
                                             message);
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
  gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

You have to add `"%s"` to the arguments of the `gtk_message_dialog_new()` function like this:

```
static void show_message (gchar *message, GtkMessageType type) {
  GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, 0, type,
                                             GTK_BUTTONS_OK, "%s",
                                             message);
  gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
  gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

Basically, the lack of `"%s"` is considered non-secure by `gcc`.

You can read more about it here:

- [warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419293/warning-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments)
- http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/148565-gtk_message_dialog_new-showing-literal-warning.html